# Deriving the Semi-Bluffing Formula in Poker

Tags: probability, poker

I am recently taking this [MIT Open course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/15-s50-poker-theory-and-analytics-january-iap-2015/resources/mit15_s50iap15_l4_preflop/), and trying to derive the Semi-Bluffing formula on my own. The formula can be found on Page 52 of the [slide](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/15-s50-poker-theory-and-analytics-january-iap-2015/b224c39d36b136343a739f53ee3c24f2_MIT15_S50IAP15_L3_Basic.pdf).

I am a bit confused about why there is a $2$ in front of the formula:

$$Fold\% = \frac{-2 \cdot BetAmt \cdot Win\% + BetAmt - Pot \cdot Win\%}{-2 \cdot BetAmt \cdot Win\% + BetAmt - Pot \cdot Win\% + Pot}$$

The $Fold\%$ required to have a positive Expected Value should be
$$Fold\% = \frac{-EV_{call}}{-EV_{call}+ Pot}$$
Since $EV_{fold} = Pot \cdot Fold\% + EV_{call} \cdot (1-Fold\%)$

Where is the factor of $2$ came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value conditional on them calling is $$ EV_{call}= Win\% \cdot(BetAmt + Pot) +(1-Win\%)\cdot(-BetAmt)$$ which rearranges to $$ 2 \cdot Win\% \cdot BetAmt + Win\%\cdot Pot -BetAmt $$

Comment: Thank you. I think I was confused about the definition of Pot Size. I thought it was the size after the opponent bet.